# Не запускается анимация модального окна.Выручайте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть вот такое модальное окно с анимацией  `codepen.io/giana/pen/gPGGgE`

```js
var num = 15;

var modalBtn = document.querySelector('.open');
var closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close');

var modalContainer = document.querySelector('.modals');
var holdModals = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('modal-drop');
  div.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)) + 'vh';
  div.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)) + 'vw';
  div.style.transitionDelay = Math.random() + 's';
  holdModals.appendChild(div);
}
console.log();
modalContainer.appendChild(holdModals);

modalBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  modalContainer.style.display = 'block';
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    modalContainer.classList.add('active');
  }, 0.1);
});

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  modalContainer.classList.remove('active');

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    modalContainer.style.display = 'none';
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
}

.modals {
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.modals.active .modal-drop {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.modals.active .modal-content {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in 1.5s;
}

.modal-drop {
  background: #141221;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150vh;
  height: 150vh;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -75vh;
  margin-top: -75vh;
  transition: -webkit-transform 2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.6, 1), -webkit-transform-origin 0s;
  transition: transform 2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.6, 1), transform-origin 0s;
  transition: transform 2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.6, 1), transform-origin 0s, -webkit-transform 2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.6, 1), -webkit-transform-origin 0s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.001);
  transform: scale(0.001);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.modal-content {
  background: #141221;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s 0s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal-wrap {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 50em;
}


/* Page Styling */

::-moz-selection {
  background: #ffc44d;
  color: #fff;
}

::selection {
  background: #ffc44d;
  color: #fff;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #ffc44d;
  color: #fff;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #e8e6e3;
  color: #1a3c4d;
  font: 1.125em/1.65 "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  background: #fff;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 20em;
  padding: 3em;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.card::before {
  content: '';
  border: 1px dotted #75f0d1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.25em;
  right: 1.25em;
  bottom: 1.25em;
  left: 1.25em;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card p {
  margin: 0.5em 0 1em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4f7e5;
}

.open,
.close {
  background: linear-gradient(#92e8bb, #77e4b7);
  border: 1px solid #77e4b7;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3cddb4;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.4em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #3cddb4;
  transition: 0.3s;
  float: right;
}

.open:hover,
.close:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(90%) contrast(120%);
  filter: brightness(90%) contrast(120%);
}

.open:focus,
.close:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #92e8bb;
  outline: none;
}

.close {
  background: linear-gradient(#fa5433, #fa3333);
  border: 1px solid #fa3333;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #d60505;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #d60505;
}

.close:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fa5433;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt deserunt velit in blanditiis, cupiditate possimus sapiente tenetur porro accusantium animi?</p>

  <button class="open">Modal</button>
</div>

<div class="modals">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-wrap">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore ab officiis libero reiciendis voluptas hic quas sit aspernatur exercitationem numquam obcaecati dolore sed voluptates, at aliquam cum harum, necessitatibus, expedita quod et magni?
        Possimus maiores vero suscipit ipsum veritatis, omnis pariatur magnam voluptatibus quisquam sequi veniam quas, et, dignissimos perspiciatis.</p>
      <button class="close">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

У меня есть переделанное (на jquery, и html немножко изменен) окно в котором можно создавать несколько кнопок с разными модальными окнами но без анимации.  http://jsfiddle.net/Telion/41j8yro3/

```js
$('.open').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let modal = $(this).attr("modal");
  $("#" + modal).css({
    display: 'flex'
  }).stop().animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 300);
});

$('.close').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents('.modal-content').stop().animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 300).css({
    display: 'none'
  });
})
```

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
}

.modal-content {
  background: hsl(250, 30%, 10%);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s 0s;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal-wrap {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 50em;
  color:white;
}


/* Page Styling */

$font-size: 18/16*1em;
::selection {
  background: hsl(40, 100%, 65%);
  color: #fff;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: hsl(40, 100%, 65%);
  color: #fff;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: hsl(30, 10%, 90%);
  color: hsl(200, 50%, 20%);
  font: #{$font-size}/1.65 'Open Sans',
  sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  background: #fff;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 20em;
  padding: 3em;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  &::before {
    content: '';
    border: 1px dotted hsl(165, 80%, 70%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.25em;
    right: 1.25em;
    bottom: 1.25em;
    left: 1.25em;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  p {
    margin: 0.5em 0 1em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid hsl(149, 70%, 90%);
    //text-align: center;
    //font-style: italic;
    //font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  }
}

.open,
.close {
  background: linear-gradient(hsl(149, 65%, 74%), hsl(155, 67%, 68%));
  border: 1px solid hsl(155, 67%, 68%);
  border-bottom: 4px solid hsl(165, 70%, 55%);
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.4em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 hsl(165, 70%, 55%);
  transition: 0.3s;
  &:hover {
    filter: brightness(90%) contrast(120%);
  }
  &:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px hsl(149, 65%, 74%);
    outline: none;
  }
  float: right;
}

.close {
  background: linear-gradient(hsl(10, 95%, 59%), hsl(360, 95%, 59%));
  border: 1px solid hsl(360, 95%, 59%);
  border-bottom: 4px solid hsl(360, 95%, 43%);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 hsl(360, 95%, 43%);
  &:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px hsl(10, 95%, 59%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt deserunt velit in blanditiis, cupiditate possimus sapiente tenetur porro accusantium animi?</p>
  <button class="open" modal="modal1">Modal</button>
  <button class="open" modal="modal2">Moda2</button>
</div>


<div id="modal2" class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-wrap">
    <p>Пример 2</p>
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="modal1" class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-wrap">
    <p>Пример 1</p>
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

И я добавляю такой скрипт до переделанного окна и добавляю с самого первого примера все стили `.modal-drop` но анимация не происходит

```js
var num = 15;
var modalContainer = document.querySelector('.modal-content');
var holdModals = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('modal-drop');
  div.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)) + 'vh';
  div.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)) + 'vw';
  div.style.transitionDelay = Math.random() + 's';
  holdModals.appendChild(div);
}

console.log();
modalContainer.appendChild(holdModals);
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: вообще работает анимация ... закрывается только быстро

Comment: @МаксимЛенский мне нужна анимация как в 1 примере...